# WebSocket Protocol stumper

Tags: webserver, socket, c++

I am writing an embedded WebSocket server and working directly from the relevant RFC.

My server responds properly to the upgrade request from the browser and the browser, in its example javascript, proceeds to send a short message through the newly established socket. So it's all working fine.

The message is short (complete frame is only 21 bytes) and contains all relevant fields which my server happily decodes.

The problem is in bits 9 to 15 which are supposed to contain the length of the payload.

Here is an hex dump of the captured message on WireShark:

```
81 8f 11 ab d5 0b 5c ce  a6 78 70 cc b0 2b 65 c4  f5 78 74 c5 b1
```

As you can see the first byte contains FIN (1 bit), RSVD1 (1 bit), RSVD2 (1 bit), RSVD3 (1 bit) and the 4 bits of the opcode. So far so good.

`8f` is the problem: it contains the MASK bit and the payload length. The MASK bit is set at 1, which is fine, but the remaining 7 bits have a value of 71 (0x47) when the entire frame is only 21 bytes long and the payload is only 15 bytes long.

So what am I doing wrong?

I can decode the message by applying the XOR mask to the payload but the length is the problem as it governs the decoding loop and goes on 71 iterations instead of the 15 that it should.

Answer (score 1):

My structure was failing to take in account that AMD64 is little-endian ordered, not big-endian.